# PresentViewController crashed my app

Tags: ios, uialertview, presentviewcontroller

I got a very strange error when I try to present a viewcontroller from a UIAlertview button.
It crashed on the prsentViewController line. Backtrace shows it failed to loadView. How can I fix this? The source code is below:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (alertView == _alertView) {
        switch (buttonIndex) {
            case 0:
            {
                [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES];
            }

                break;

            default:
            {
                NSString *nibName = IS_IPAD? NSStringFromClass([UINewUserAccountViewController class]) : [NSStringFromClass([UINewUserAccountViewController class]) stringByAppendingString:@"~iPhone"];
                UINewUserAccountViewController *newUserAccountViewController = [[UINewUserAccountViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nibName  bundle:nil];
                newUserAccountViewController.delegate = self;

                UINavigationController *navi = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newUserAccountViewController];
                [self presentViewController:navi animated:YES completion:nil];

            }
                break;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the error message.

Comment: **very strange error when I try to present a viewcontroller from a UIAlertview button.** -- this is not the issue, check the default block, which all defined in the proper way

Comment: @KumarKL What do you mean by default block? and what's the proper way? Can you post an answer below?

Comment: @rckoenes There is no error message. It just stops at main function and throws an exception which can only be seen by typing backtrace in LLDB. It tells me it failed at loadview of UIViewController. The exception comes from the line `[self presentViewController:...]`

Comment: @newguy hit continue a couple of time, there will be an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @rckoenes 's help I finally found the error after I hit a couple of times when I get the exception. It stops at UIViewController loadFromNibName because the line

```
[NSStringFromClass([UINewUserAccountViewController class]) stringByAppendingString:@"~iPhone"]
```

returns a nib name but in the xib file with that name the root view is not a file outlet. After I link the view to file outlet the exception goes away.